# How to decode private key in to byte array

Tags: key, private, decode

I have a requirement in which I want to decode the RSA private key into the byte array. 
Is there any way to decode the private key from PEM/DER format to byte array? Solution in any language will be helpful.

A sample code will be helpful.

Vishal N

Comment: What language/platform? What format is the PK in?

Comment: Language - Java. Private key is in PEM format.

Comment: See the answer here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600106/create-privatekey-from-byte-array/6377471#6377471  You must replace "DSA" with "RSA".