# Extracting algorithm ID from bytes of encoded private key

Tags: java, cryptography, asn.1, pkcs#8

**Is it possible to create a `PrivateKey` from an encoded byte array alone, *without knowing the algorithm in advance*?**

So in a way it's a twist on [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600106/create-privatekey-from-byte-array), that's not adressed in the answers.

Say I have a pair of keys generated this way:

```java
KeyPair keyPair = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA").generateKeyPair(); // Could be "EC" instead of "RSA"
String privateKeyB64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded());
writePrivateKeyToSafeLocation(privateKeyB64);
```

To obtain a `PrivateKey` from the base64-encoded bytes, I can do this, but I have to know the algorithm family in advance:

```java
String privateKeyB64 = readPrivateKeyFromSafeLocation();
EncodedKeySpec encodedKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(privateKeyB64));
byte[] encodedKeyBytes = encodedKeySpec.getEncoded();
String algorithmFamily = "RSA"; // Can this be deduced from encodedKeyBytes?
PrivateKey key = KeyFactory.getInstance(algorithmFamily).generatePrivate(encodedKeySpec);
```

Unfortunately `encodedKeySpec.getAlgorithm()` returns `null`.

I'm pretty sure the algorithm ID is actually specified within those bytes in PKCS#8 format, but I'm not sure how to read the ASN.1 encoding.

**Can I "sniff" the algorithm ID in a reliable way from those bytes?**

It's OK to only support RSA and EC (algorithms supported by the JRE, without additional providers).

To get an idea of what I'm after, here is an attempt that seems to work empirically:

```java
private static final byte[] EC_ASN1_ID = {42, -122, 72, -50, 61, 2, 1};
private static final byte[] RSA_ASN1_ID = {42, -122, 72, -122, -9, 13, 1, 1, 1};
private static final int EC_ID_OFFSET = 9;
private static final int RSA_ID_OFFSET = 11;

private static String sniffAlgorithmFamily(byte[] keyBytes) {
    if (Arrays.equals(Arrays.copyOfRange(keyBytes, EC_ID_OFFSET, EC_ID_OFFSET + EC_ASN1_ID.length), EC_ASN1_ID)) {
        return "EC";
    }
    if (Arrays.equals(Arrays.copyOfRange(keyBytes, RSA_ID_OFFSET, RSA_ID_OFFSET + RSA_ASN1_ID.length), RSA_ASN1_ID)) {
        return "RSA";
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Illegal key, this thingy requires either RSA or EC private key");
}
```

But I have no idea if that is safe to use. Maybe the IDs are not always at those offsets. Maybe they can be encoded in some other ways...

Comment: The good news: all the information is in there as metadata, somewhere. The bad news: for elliptic curves at least the same curve may be specified in different ways, so there isn't a canonical one-and-only representation for a given elliptic curve. As for parsing out the metadata, if you are probably better off using a proper ASN.1 parsing library like for example Bouncycastle, but it can also be done "by hand" in the manner you are doing if you are careful. Finally, there are non-supported `DerThisAndThat` classes in the `sun.*` namespace you can use if you are a hateful person.

Comment: I wonder if it isn't easier just to speculatively create the key using the `KeyFactory.generatePrivate()` for one key type, then catch the appropriate exceptions and try the next key type until `generatePrivate()` succeeds. Then the actual `PrivateKey` instance can be probed to see what it is.

Comment: Thanks, I've considered parsing ASN.1 but I'd also need to implement some PKCS#8 logic on top, that I might get wrong. Trying all standard algos would actually be a good idea! Is there a way to dynamically get the list of supported algos for KeyPairs, or do I have to hardcode it to `["EC", "RSA", "DSA", "DiffieHellman"]`? --Hmm maybe _that_ should be a distinct (and much simpler) question...

Comment: So yeah there is, it will work fine for my need, but it's a shame that the JCA cannot do better than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by James in comments, trying every supported algorithm would work, in a much safer way.

It's possible to dynamically obtain the list of such algorithms:

```
Set<String> supportedKeyPairAlgorithms() {
    Set<String> algos = new HashSet<>();
    for (Provider provider : Security.getProviders()) {
        for (Provider.Service service : provider.getServices()) {
            if ("KeyPairGenerator".equals(service.getType())) {
                algos.add(service.getAlgorithm());
            }
        }
    }
    return algos;
}
```

And with that, just try them all to generate the `KeyPair`:

```
PrivateKey generatePrivateKey(String b64) {
    byte[] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(b64);
    for (String algorithm : supportedKeyPairAlgorithms()) {
        try {
            LOGGER.debug("Attempting to decode key as " + algorithm);
            return KeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm).generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(bytes));
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            LOGGER.warn("Standard algorithm " + algorithm + " not known by this Java runtime from outer space", e);
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            LOGGER.debug("So that key is not " + algorithm + ", nevermind", e);
        }
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("No standard KeyFactory algorithm could decode your key");
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer, allowing one to decode a public key without requiring Bouncy Castle. Although I would have thrown an InvalidKeySpecificationException, instead of a RuntimeException. It's neater that way.